# How to align input boxes in a form

Tags: css, input, html-table

I'm looking for a way to make the inputs straight using CSS. I already used a table and it doesn't work.

Here is a picture of the misaligned input boxes:

[image: Misaligned boxes]

**CODE**

```
<form action="register2.php" method="POST">
     <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
        First Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname">
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td>
        UserName: <input type="text" name="uname">
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email1">
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td>
        Confirm Email : <input type="text" name="email2">
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass1">
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td>
        Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2">
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register">
        <tr>
        <td>
     </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: how about using `table`?

Comment: i tried it and it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the structure of your table is somewhat wrong..

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>FirstName:</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>LastName:</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>UserName:</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="email" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/aqm7kjbg/1/

Just do the rest yourself... =) cheerio!

Comment: @orange18 LMAO, Np bro... happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use `text align` and `float` like this:

```css
label{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: left; /*Change to right here if you want it close to the inputs*/
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
 <html>
  <div>
      <label>First Name:</label><input type="text">
      <label>Last Name:</label><input type="text">
      <label>Email:</label><input type = "text">
      <label>Username:</label><input type="text">
  </div>
 </html>
```

Comment: thank you programming is fun there are so many things to solved the problem